# Apple's MFI - ATS box did not respond to initialization requests

Tags: mfi

Could you guys help me?

I acquired an ATS box + Beagle USB 480 + USB Breakout Board of Avinet, to test some MFI developments.

It worked without problems (off some conections problems at the very start of his use), two weeks long.

Today, we tried to run some tests here, but the ATS software  crashed, trying to update ATS box firmware.

Since this problem happened, when we try to run the "Capture" function of the ATS sw, we receive this message:

> The ATS Box did not respond to initialization requests

Is very strange because the ATS sw finds the ATS Box and the Beagle, who are attached to the Mac, but couldn`t initialize the ATS Box.

I supose that, when the ATS sw crashed, trying to update ATS box firmware, the firmware itself was damaged. The problem is that I don't know how to re-install the ATS box firmware.

Just to complete the scenario,I'm running the ATS sw at a MacBook Air, (Mac OS X 10.7.3).

Could someone please help me? How could I identify the problem, and solve it?

Comment: Just curious as to whether you got an answer for this problem. I am sure the folks at TotalPhase could probably help.